# What are Google Apps Accounts?

Tags: backup, synchronization, gmail, contacts

I want to purchase [this](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/interstitialRedirect?domain&productListingId=5941%2016825965296321823984&pli=1) backup plan for $3/m but when I go ahead for signup it says:

> This application requires a Google
>   Apps account.

What does that mean? I'm a regular gmail user and I want to backup emails and contacts.

Comment: Google Apps ≠ gmail.com!

Answer (score 2):

It means you need a Gmail account hosted on Google Servers,accessible on your domain using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html).

Try [Backupify's plan](http://www.backupify.com/socialmediabackup) for normal Gmail accounts